# More than one inverse relationship to the same entity in core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, swift, relationship, entity-relationship

I'm trying to build a "Comic Book" database using Core Data.

I've created a "Book" entity and an "Artist" entity. An "Artist" entity represents anyone who can work on a comic book - a writer, colorist etc...

I've created two relationships between the "Book" entity and the "Artist" entity - one for "script" and one for "pencils".  Each of these relationships should also be inverted - each "Book" entity should know its writer and each writer should know all the book he has worked on. Same goes for pencils.
The problem is that Xcode only allows one inverted relationship for same classes.

[image]

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using entity inheritance as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html